# Can't get C++ Boost Pointer Serialization to work

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

This question is not the same as the one listed as duplicate:
[Boost c++ serializing a char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094750/boost-c-serializing-a-char)
I am not using shared_ptr, and I have full access to the internals of my classes.

The closest response I could find was in [Store a vector of pointers to custom objects to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283800/store-a-vector-of-pointers-to-custom-objects-to-file) which I found by searching for the compiler error.

However, the answer given there was not clear, at least not to me. It points back to the boost docs, which indicate that the simple code I have listed here should work. After cataloguing all the housekeeping that goes into serializing objects by pointer, the boost docs say this.

> This serialization library addresses all of the above considerations.

If I must write a char[] one character at a time, or if I must dereference all pointer objects in a container and break them down to their constituent POD parts, writing their sizes in bytes to the stream first, in order to serialize with boost, then there doesn't seem to be much point in using boost. That's the lion's share of the work. Creating a text output stream and squirting bytes into it is trivial.

I'm not above saying that I may have a reading comprehension issue with the docs, but from my understanding of what I've read, the code snippet below should work. However, this code emits the following compiler error. So, I must be omitting something, but I just can't see it, so that's why I'm asking for help.

How about simply pointing out the failure point in the code snippet below? Or, even better, providing a snippet that does work?

```
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘class boost::ptr_vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ has no member named ‘serialize’
         t.serialize(ar, file_version);
         ^
```

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

class A {
public:
        A(){}

        char c;
        char *name;

        friend boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>

        void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned version) 
        {
                ar &  name;
        }
};

main()
{
        A a;
        a.name = (char *)"this is a test";

        std::ofstream ofs("table.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive os(ofs);
        os << a;
}
```

I can serialize int, char, even STL types, but I cannot serialize anything with a pointer. For example, I can serialize `std::vector<std::string>`, but if I attempt to serialize `std::vector<std::string *>`, I will get the compiler error.

Comment: @Mr.Kbok I was doing the same. \@OP Does that look like HTML for you? Could you "Run the snippet"?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original answer? I cannot find it.

Comment: It's printed at the top: http://i.imgur.com/b7hVWxj.png
 Perhaps you have to refresh your browser if there was some kind of error displaying the page earlier.

Comment: Oh well. The answer was there in the linked duplicate - if you looked for it. I've written up an answer here. I agree that the "alternative case" was not particularly welldone in that answer, but then again, no one should be recommending that anyways, for reasons demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Re. "How about simply pointing out the failure point in the code snippet below? Or, even better, providing a snippet that does work?" - How about you realize that people might not have the time? I pointed you at the existing answer assuming that you read it for what it means, and hoping you'd appreciate having an answer 4 hours earlier. You're not **entitled** to an answer. I was trying to be helpful.

Comment: Sorry if I came across wrongly. I just didn't see the answer in that post. I understand that most people who help out in these forums have real work to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I must write a char[] one character at a time, or if I must dereference all pointer objects in a container and break them down to their constituent POD parts, writing their sizes in bytes to the stream first, in order to serialize with boost, then there doesn't seem to be much point in using boost.

Yes. But you're trying to serialize a pointer. What should a pointer to `char` be serialized as? Surely `T*` should serialize a dynamically allocated `T`, no? So you would expect to serialize a single `char` unless `name` were `nullptr`?

Or do you expect to get full object tracking for each character serialized?

The whole point here is that you chose a raw pointer to a primitive type. The pointer lacks the necessary information. Hence, the onus is on you to add the information. If you find that *tedious*, you're free to use C++ types instead.

Note, by the way, that this is not legal in C++03 and up anyways:

```
a.name = (char *)"this is a test";
```

A static cast from `char const(&)[15]` to `char *` would drop a const qualification. Your compiler should reject this code anyways.

Here's my take on it (use `std::string`):

```
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

class A {
  public:
    std::string name;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar & name;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a { "this is a test" };
    boost::archive::text_oarchive os(std::cout);
    os << a;
}
```

Incidentally, the linked duplicate question's title exactly matches what you're trying to do here: **[Boost c++ serializing a char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094750/boost-c-serializing-a-char)** and the accepted answer displays exactly the same solution.

If you **really** insist, you can of course go mud-wrestle some C-style code for no glory:

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

class A {
  public:
    A(char const* sz = nullptr) : name(sz? strdup(sz) : nullptr) {}
    A(A const&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A const&) = delete;

    ~A() { free(name); }

  private:
    char* name;

    template <class Archive> void save(Archive &ar, unsigned) const {
        bool have_name = name;
        ar & have_name;

        if (have_name)
        {
            size_t len = strlen(name);
            ar & len;
            ar & boost::serialization::make_binary_object(name, len);
        }
    }

    template <class Archive> void load(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        bool have_name = name;
        ar & have_name;

        if (!have_name)
        {
            free(name);
            name = nullptr;
        } else
        {
            size_t len = 0;
            ar & len;

            name = static_cast<char*>(realloc(name, len));
            ar & boost::serialization::make_binary_object(name, len);
        }
    }

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};


int main() {
    A a { "this is a test" };
    boost::archive::text_oarchive os(std::cout);
    os << a;
}
```

But all this gains you is 6x as much code, crippled value semantics, completely abandoned separation of concerns, a lot of bug potential (did you think of the difference between having `name==null` and `strlen(name)==0`? Currently my implementation [employs unspecified (implementation-defined) behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc). I'll leave it as an exercise to you, the reader, to come up with airtight handling here)  and... not even readable string output.

> Yes, of course `make_array` would give you `14 116 104 105 115 32 105 115 32 97 32 116 101 115 116` instead of `dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=`, but that's horrifically storage inefficient and still not human readable.

Comment: Thank you for the considered reply. So, I guess the short answer is to avoid serializing with pointers to objects. Serializing a vector of pointers to a class, e.g. 'vector<myClass *>' would invite the same complications, where as 'vector<myClass>' works out of the box.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve  is interfacing with C code that gathers a mass of information for later analysis. I have to use the C for the data gathering, as it uses headers that won't compile in c++.

Comment: `extern "C"` should help. And you can't use Boost Serialization in C mode anyways. If you also want to deserialize, you will still have to think about allocating the memory anyways.

Comment: I thought boost serialization would be a good way to store the data, which is quite complicated, having the properties of a nested hierarchy and a graph. If it weren't for the nature of the data, I would simply use fprintf() and be done with it. :)

Comment: Understdood. I have #ifdef __cplusplus extern C in headers shared by both the C and C++ sources. That part works just fine. Just that C provides all the information with pointers.

Comment: And, yes, I will have to deserialize, as I must provide a lookup app. That one can be written entirely in C++, since I won't need the C libs once the original data has been serialized.

Comment: Well. I'd be inclined to say that unless your data structures _own_ the data (which they don't if you can't equivalently use `std::string`), then you're not actually serializing at all! Serialization implies generating a representation of the object's ***internal state*** - so it can be reconstructed from that representation. If that's not what you want here, then all you apparently want to do is generate an output stream from some data. ...

Comment: Boost Spirit Karma comes closer to that (and you could use Qi to parse it back, but **not** into the same structure, unless you intend to  duplicate the same C-style awkwardness of the data gathering API

Comment: When building the lists and vectors, I can simply push the dereferenced object into the container and pass its address back to the C code when needed.

Comment: Why not parse into a proper C++ datastructure, but use custom allocators (Boost Interprocess) to store directly into a memory mapped file? This ensures that you can (a) instantly "open" the stored database of gathered data and (b) handle databases much larger than physical memory.

Comment: I'd move this to chat, but I haven't the creds to do that yet. Let me say that I do own the data structures, and I can stringize the character pointers, as well as dereferencing any of  the other objects the C code creates. Thank you again for your extended help. If there's a place where I can bump your creds, let me know.

Comment: @TonyCamuso the "creds" (rep) are a community thing. People will vote if they find my answer helpful. ***[That's how it works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)*** :) I was more talking about letting the C++ containers own the data (as in manage their allocation and lifetimes). That'll make life a lot easier. And you still have full control/flexibility by using allocators.

Comment: If you're curious, you can peruse the current state of the project (it's open source) at https://github.com/camuso/kabiparser/tree/master. The README is woefully out of date, but it gives the general idea.

Comment: The containers are in C++  headers, with C++ specific stuff hidden from the C source with #ifdef __cplusplus. The only real problem I was having was understanding the role of pointers in the boost serialization milieu.